# Django REST - JSON API results as list by key

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I have a very basic API made with Django Rest Framework with an output as follows:

```
[
    {
        "name": "John",
        "city": "chicago",
        "age": "22"
    },
    {
        "name": "Gary",
        "city": "florida",
        "age": "35"
    },
    {
        "name": "Selena",
        "city": "vegas",
        "age": "18"
    }
]
```

I want to convert it to the following format to simplify the usage of its data in charts.

```
{
    "name": ["John", "Gary", "Selena"]
    "city": ["chicago", "vegas", "florida"]
    "age": ["22", "35", "18"]
}
```

1. Is there a simple way this can be done in Javascript (and Python just for curiosity)?

**2. Can this be proactively solved by adjusting the Serializer or the ViewSet in DRF?**

Comment: you want python code or javascript code

Comment: In the 1st question I explicitly ask javascript and, if possible, python. Then the 2nd question is Python.

Comment: you can use it for both to convert.  if you convert in python level it will be used for some other frontend. or else you want to convert frontend again and again

Comment: This is why I ask my 2nd question :) do you know a pythonic way to deal with this?

Comment: yes I know, you can fetch the data two-level. one is the serializer level  and one is query set level or normal for loop

Answer (score 2):

Javascript version:

```js
const data = [
    {
        name: 'John',
        city: 'chicago',
        age: '22',
    },
    {
        name: 'Gary',
        city: 'florida',
        age: '35',
    },
    {
        name: 'Selena',
        city: 'vegas',
        age: '18',
    },
];

const result = Object.keys(data[0]).reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = data.map(_ => _[key]);
    return obj;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python you could do it like this:

```py
data = [
    {
        "name": "John",
        "city": "chicago",
        "age": "22"
    },
    {
        "name": "Gary",
        "city": "florida",
        "age": "35"
    },
    {
        "name": "Selena",
        "city": "vegas",
        "age": "18"
    }
]

result = {}

for key in data[0]:
    result[key] = []

for entry in data:
    for key in entry:
        result[key].append(entry[key])

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
data = [
    {
        "name": "John",
        "city": "chicago",
        "age": "22"
    },
    {
        "name": "Gary",
        "city": "florida",
        "age": "35"
    },
    {
        "name": "Selena",
        "city": "vegas",
        "age": "18"
    }
]
output = []
name = []
city = []
age = []

for i in data:
    name.append(i['name'])
    city.append(i['city'])
    age.append(i['age'])
output.append({"name":name,"city":city,"age":age})
print(output)
```